# How should I execute functions only one after another in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, synchronous

I am trying to make a time conversion tool, first thing it does is gets the co-ordinates of both the cities you enter and then calculates time accordingly.

But the problem I am facing is that the function which gets the co-ordinates takes some time and it is asynchronous as well and thus there are issues with the execution order.

Is there are a way I can make sure that execution of a next statement gets done one after the previous completes?

```
function initializeConversion() {

    //Gets the date from non hidden fields and converts it to the format which is required
    if (document.getElementById('datenh1').value.length == 0) //Finds the non-empty field
        setValueOfDateTwo();
    else
        setValueOfDateOne();

    //Get the value from the fields
    cityOneString = document.getElementById('city1').value;
    cityTwoString = document.getElementById('city2').value; 

    //Logging Statements
    console.log("City 1: "+cityOneString);
    console.log("City 2: "+cityTwoString);

    //Gets the coordinates of both cities
    //This is where the issue is
    getCoordinates(cityOneString);
    getCoordinates(cityTwoString);
}
```

You can check the whole code here on github:
https://github.com/udit96rc/TimeConverter

You can check the tool here: http://uditchugh.me/pt

Comment: Give `Promise` a try.

Comment: @Leo Yeah. Was reading about it. Will use it next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `getCoordinates` you use asynchronous request to Google API via `geocoder.geocode()` call. The second argument in this method is an actual callback which is executed when the request is done. Pass own callback function to `getCoordinates` function (as a second argument) and call it once the actual request is finished processing.

```
function getCoordinates(city, callback) {
   ...

   geocoder.geocode({ address: address }, function(results, status) {
       ...
       if (typeof callback === 'function')
           callback();
   });
}

getCoordinates(cityOneString, function() {
    getCoordinates(cityTwoString);
});
```

Comment: Can you please show the change here? I am pretty new to JavaScript. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try this and get back soon.

Comment: Yes. Saw it already and implemented it as well. It works. Thanks again.